# Python double list comprehension

Tags: python, arrays, list-comprehension

I have a list of strings read from a file I need to turn into a 2D array:

```
IN >> lines = ['0.1;0;0;0;', '0.2;0;0;0;', '0.3;1;1;1;', '0.4;2;2;2;', '0.5;0;0;0;']
# Goes on for a few thousand lines
```

Note each string ends in `;`.

I need to exclude lines with all zeroes (some lines are all zeroes at the start and at the end)

I `.split()` on `;` but `filter` `None` to remove the empty values I will get at the end of each returned array from the `.split()`.

```
data_array = [list(filter(None, line.split(';'))) for line in lines if line.split(';')[1] != '0']

OUT >> data_array = [[0.1, 0, 0, 0], [0.2, 0, 0, 0], [0.3, 1, 1, 1], [0.4, 2, 2, 2], [0.5, 0, 0, 0]]
```

This is kind of returning the 2D array I need, but including the arrays with all zeroes, so my conditional must be at the wrong place. Except I thought conditions at the end of a list comprehension filter the elements that go into the list.

Then I thought I needed to filter on the "inside" array:

```
data_array = [[l for l in (filter(None, line.split(';'))) if l != '0'] for line in lines]

OUT >> data_array = [[0.1], [0.2], [0.3, 1, 1, 1], [0.4, 2, 2, 2], [0.5]]
```

Except this is removing the zeroes but leaving the marker (the first element of each array is a marker)

What I'm looking to get is just the arrays that contain numbers but not zeroes

```
DESIRED OUTPUT >> data_array = [[0.3, 1, 1, 1], [0.4, 2, 2, 2]]
```

Comment: I just ran `lines = ['0.1;0;0;0;', '0.2;0;0;0;', '0.3;1;1;1;', '0.4;2;2;2;', '0.5;0;0;0;']

data_array = [list(filter(None, line.split(';'))) for line in lines if line.split(';')[1] != '0']

print(data_array)` and it gives your desired output for me of `[['0.3', '1', '1', '1'], ['0.4', '2', '2', '2']]`

Comment: The only difference between the example and my actual code was that I was slicing the `lines` list to start at a specific index (to ignore headers) so mine is `lines[data_start:]`. Is slicing mutating the array in some way then?

Comment: Can you share the actual structure you are dealing with then?  You don't have to have thousands of lines, but the way the data is raw would help.  It is possible that the slicing is changing things, but without the actual structure it is hard to tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is cleaner to do this over multiple lines and not using the `filter(None, ...)` as you can just use `line[:-1]`, to emit the last character. First creating the list in lists, can be done by:

```
nested_list = [line[:-1].split(';') for line in lines]
```

You can then iterate over the inner lists to check if they contain a 0:

```
filtered_list = [line for line in nested_list if '0' not in line]
```

Then we need to convert everything to floats:

```
result = [list(map(float, line)) for line in filtered_list]
```

Or if you really want to have a one-liner:

```
result = [list(map(float, line)) for line in [line[:-1].split(';') for line in lines] if '0' not in line]
```

Comment: The conditional `if '0' not in line` was making the generator skip some lines, so I changed it to the more explicit `if line[1] != '0'` (index 1 of each line array, which is where values start to reside after the marker at index 0)

Answer (score 1):

```
[ x
  for x in ([ float(v) for v in line.split(';') if v ]
            for line in lines)
  if any(x[1:]) ]
```

We have an inner generator which iterates all lines, splits each line, removes the empty strings and converts all remaining values to floats.  Then we have an outer loop which checks each of these results for containing only zeros by using the `any()` function on all but the first element.

This produces all floats.  If you need only the first element in each line to be a float and the rest shall be integers, then use this extension:

```
[ x
  for x in ([ (int if i else float)(v)
              for i, v in enumerate(line.split(';'))
              if v ]
            for line in lines)
  if any(x[1:]) ]
```